# Waypoints not working when element is initially hidden

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I have the following code:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;  
    height: 949px;
    display: none;
}
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: black;
}
.pink-curve {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/pink-curve.png);
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 72px;
    top: 206px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer">
    <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF;">SCROLL DOWN</h1>
    <h1 id="clickme" style="color: #FFFFFF;">CLICK TO SHOW WRAPPER DIV</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="pink-curve"></span>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#clickme').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.wrapper').show();
    });

    var curve1 = jQuery('.pink-curve');
    curve1.waypoint(function(direction) {
        curve1.css({"height" : "30px", "width" : "80px"});
    }, {
        offset: '70%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "80px", "width" : "80px"});
    }, {
        offset: '68%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "100px", "width" : "80px"});
    }, {
        offset: '66%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "165px", "width" : "100px"});
    }, {
        offset: '64%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "200px", "width" : "180px"});
    }, {
        offset: '62%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "240px", "width" : "180px"});
    }, {
        offset: '60%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "180px"});
    }, {
        offset: '58%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "220px"});
    }, {
        offset: '56%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "270px"});
    }, {
        offset: '54%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "320px"});
    }, {
        offset: '52%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "370px"});
    }, {
        offset: '50%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "430px"});
    }, {
        offset: '48%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "480px"});
    }, {
        offset: '46%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "520px"});
    }, {
        offset: '44%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "570px"});
    }, {
        offset: '42%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "620px"});
    }, {
        offset: '40%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "670px"});
    }, {
        offset: '38%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "720px"});
    }, {
        offset: '36%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "770px"});
    }, {
        offset: '34%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "820px"});
    }, {
        offset: '32%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "870px"});
    }, {
        offset: '30%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "905px"});
    }, {
        offset: '28%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "365px", "width" : "949px"});
    }, {
        offset: '26%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "405px", "width" : "949px"});
    }, {
        offset: '24%'
    });
    curve1.waypoint(function() {
        curve1.css({"height" : "436px", "width" : "949px"});
    }, {
        offset: '22%'
    });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98y5j9c8/7/).

If I remove `display: none;` from `.wrapper` it works fine, it just won't work if the element is hidden and then displayed afterwards.

Any idea's on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `show` method. I could be wrong, but I believe the show method overwrites the `hidden` class which you don't have cascaded with the `wrapper` element. Instead, do the following:

```
jQuery('#clickme').on('click', function() {
   jQuery('.wrapper').css('display','block');
});
```

According to comments below:

If you want it to be loaded on scroll as well, you can initiate the scroll function and specify the distance in the y axis that you want it to appear after the document has scrolled to that point.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
      $('.wrapper').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.wrapper').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

The fadein method gives you a better transition but is not necessary

See your updated [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/98y5j9c8/9/)

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem unfortunately, if you remove `display: none;` from `.wrapper` you will see the line image animates on scroll. With display none and then showing the div, the animation no longer happens on scroll.

Comment: Gotcha! I edited my answer. It should give you a good base to build on. Implement animate.css or css transitions to help you get a smooth design.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you need to call `Waypoint.refreshAll()` when you make an element visible?